Can anybody share a build.gradle sample on how to use EvoSuite with Gradle
I am trying to generate tests for a Java application using EvoSuite from Gradle.
I found some tips on Gradle configuration, but when you open evosuite-standalone-runtime-1.0.6.jar, the value suggested for main (org.evosuite.EvoSuite) is not in the jar, and I haven´t been able to find any main class so far. So, what class should be declared as "main", or should you use a different approach? This is the definition I am using:
task evosuite(type: JavaExec) {
    group = "verification"
    description = "Generate tests using EvoSuite"
    classpath = files('app/libs/evosuite-standalone-runtime-1.0.6.jar')
    main = "org.evosuite.EvoSuite"
    args = [
            '-generateTests',
            '-class', 'cl.bci.MSdir.service.*',
            '-projectCP', sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.asPath,
            '-Dtest_dir=src/test/java'
    ]
}

Thanks
I tried the configuration I shared above, and I was expecting some tests being generated
